# angular2 lazy loading module routes

Tags: angular, routes

I got this on my main route module:

```
 { 
    path: 'alpha/aaa', 
    loadChildren: 'app/connection/connection.module#ConnectionModule'
  },

  { 
    path: 'num/123', 
    loadChildren: 'app/connection/connection.module#ConnectionModule'
  },

  { 
    path: 'rand/a2b1', 
    loadChildren: 'app/connection/connection.module#ConnectionModule'
  },
```

The routes are different but they are in one module because they have the same templates and functionalities.

My question is how would I map the defined paths above in the sub module's route if those are the exact path that I need? So I tried the following but didn't work:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'alpha/aaa', pathMatch:'full', component: Component1 },
  { path: 'num/123', pathMatch:'full', component: Component2 },
  { path: 'rand/a2b1', pathMatch:'full', component: Component3 }
];
```

Comment: Would this work? { path: '', component: WeAreSharingComponent }

Comment: Ow! Edited :)! They use different components.

Comment: How about this : { path: '/alpha/aaa', component: Component1 } Slash at the front for a non-relative path?

Comment: Tried but didn't work. I can separate each to have their own module and create a common module for the three. I was just thinking that there must be a way to make it work. I can't believe that someone hasn't had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that's not possible to do, but you can achieve something similar if you change your routes and give a common route for the whole module. ie:

```
{ 
    path: 'connection', 
    loadChildren: 'app/connection/connection.module#ConnectionModule'
}
```

and then as you do now

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'alpha/aaa', component: Component1 },
  { path: 'num/123', component: Component2 },
  { path: 'rand/a2b1', component: Component3 }
];
```

You would then access them like

```
/connection/alpha/aaa 
/connection/num/123
/connection/rand/a2b1
```